# can we pass parameter to the JSON_VALUE in Oracle

Tags: oracle12.1

I have a query which fetches json format data from a column. i want to fetch the data of json by passing a field_name dynamically from the column.

for example

```
SELECT SUBJECT_MARKS
FROM STUDENT
WHERE STUDENT_ID = 101
```

result is:

```js
{
    "English": "70",
    "Hindi": "80",
    "Maths": "90",
    "Science": "90",
    "Social": "85"
}
```

If I want to get the particular subject marks, then the query is:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(SUBJECT_MARKS,'$.Maths')
FROM STUDENT
WHERE STUDENT_ID = 101
```

Now the result is:

`90`

Now my requirement is to get the SUBJECT MARKS dynamically while giving the subject name as parameter in the query

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(SUBJECT_MARKS,:pSubjectMarks)
FROM STUDENT
WHERE STUDENT_ID = 101
```

while execute the query when we give the `:pSubjectMarks` as `'$.Science'`
then it is throwing the error message

> ORA-40454: path expression not a literal
> 40454. 00000 -  "path expression not a literal"
> *Cause:    The provided path expression was not a literal (a constant).
> *Action:   Provide a constant path expression.
> Error at Line: 29 Column: 45

Can anyone help me to find the solution for the query
Thanks in advance

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. You are asking about JSON_VALUE but the question is tagged specifically with `oracle11g` and `oracle10g`. JSON functions were added only in Oracle 12. So, which is which?

Comment: The error you've posted cannot appear in Oracle 11g and moreover in ancient 10g as commented above. Please, edit Oracle's version tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build the subject you want to get info from into an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement. Since all of your subjects are simple strings, you can use the `DBMS_ASSERT` package to validate the input of the `p_subject_name` parameter to prevent any SQL injection from happening.

Below is an example on how to build the procedure.

#### Setup

```sql
CREATE TABLE students
AS
    SELECT 101                                                                                        AS student_id,
              EMPTY_CLOB ()
           || '{ "English": "70", "Hindi": "80", "Maths": "90", "Science": "90", "Social": "85" }'    AS subject_marks
      FROM DUAL;
```

```sql
DECLARE
    PROCEDURE print_subject_score (p_student_id students.student_id%TYPE, p_subject_name VARCHAR2)
    IS
        l_sql     VARCHAR2 (1000);
        l_score   VARCHAR2 (5);
    BEGIN
        l_sql :=
               'select json_value(subject_marks, ''$.'
            || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME (p_subject_name)
            || ''') from students where student_id = :p_student_id';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql
            INTO l_score
            USING p_student_id;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_score);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN
            --Student ID does not exist
            NULL;
    END;
BEGIN
    print_subject_score (p_student_id => 101, p_subject_name => 'English');
    print_subject_score (p_student_id => 101, p_subject_name => 'Test');
    print_subject_score (p_student_id => 102, p_subject_name => 'Maths');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12 (when support for JSON functions was added), you could whitelist all the possible options in a `CASE` expression using either:

```sql
SELECT CASE :pSubjectMarks
       WHEN 'English' THEN JSON_VALUE(SUBJECT_MARKS,'$.English')
       WHEN 'Hindi'   THEN JSON_VALUE(SUBJECT_MARKS,'$.Hindi')
       WHEN 'Maths'   THEN JSON_VALUE(SUBJECT_MARKS,'$.Maths')
       WHEN 'Science' THEN JSON_VALUE(SUBJECT_MARKS,'$.Science')
       WHEN 'Social'  THEN JSON_VALUE(SUBJECT_MARKS,'$.Social')
       END as subject_marks
FROM   STUDENT s
```

or:

```sql
SELECT CASE :pSubjectMarks
       WHEN 'English' THEN english
       WHEN 'Hindi'   THEN hindi
       WHEN 'Maths'   THEN maths
       WHEN 'Science' THEN science
       WHEN 'Social'  THEN social
       END as subject_marks
FROM   STUDENT s
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         s.subject_marks,
         '$'
         COLUMNS (
           ENGLISH NUMBER PATH '$.English',
           HINDI   NUMBER PATH '$.Hindi',
           MATHS   NUMBER PATH '$.Maths',
           SCIENCE NUMBER PATH '$.Science',
           SOCIAL  NUMBER PATH '$.Social'
         )
       ) j
WHERE  STUDENT_ID = 101;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e8d8064b34004bff00eb9f4e18f03b01)*

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an access to the  `JSON_VALUE` function, then your Oracle version is at least 12.1. This version also provides an access to the local PL/SQL declarations in SQL queries, where you have full dynamic access to JSON keys.

So you may use `JSON_OBJECT_T` data type for this. As you may see, path is passed as a column value (expression, not a literal), and you may use bind variable in place of an expression.

> ```
> with function get_mark(
>   p_marks in varchar2,
>   p_subj in varchar2
> )
> return number
> as
>   json JSON_OBJECT_T;
> begin
>   json := JSON_OBJECT_T(p_marks);
>   return json.get_String(p_subj);
> end;
>
> select
>   t.column_value as subj,
>   get_mark(SUBJECT_MARKS, t.column_value) as mark
> from students
>   cross join sys.odcivarchar2list(
>     'English',
>     'Hindi',
>     'Maths', 
>     'Science',
>     'Social',
>     'something'
>   )  t
> where student_id = 101
> ```
>
> ```
> SUBJ      | MARK
> :-------- | ---:
> English   |   70
> Hindi     |   80
> Maths     |   90
> Science   |   90
> Social    |   85
> something | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8a4c8e3756da68543e2b03ed38276479)*